# if statement without an else using vba code, giving me a syntax error

Tags: vba, if-statement, syntax-error

```
Dim a As Long
a = range("A617:A737").Copy
s = range("A739:A" & EndLine + 2).PasteSpecial

Dim FinalLine As Long
FinalLine = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
range("B739").AutoFill Destination:=range("B739:B" & FinalLine - 2)

Cells(FinalLine + 10, 2).Formula = "= 5"

Cells("B" & FinalLine + 3).FormulaArray = _
 "= Min(If(B739:B" & FinalLine - 2 = FinalLine + 10 & " , A$739:A$" & EndLine + 2))"
```

The error is highlighting the comma after the 10.

Comment: I'm not sure what that code is suppose to read as, someone edit that please.

Comment: Please post the entire If statement. I don't see the 10, or the comma after it.

Comment: This has nothing to do with an If statement.  The syntax error is "Expected: end of statement".  You have a second assignment operator at `=  5`.  Without any other information provided, I'm assuming you're missing some quotes and concat operators.

Comment: Sorry, I am new to vba. I just posted the rest

Comment: What is `EndLine` ?  Should that be `FinalLine` ?

Comment: end line is the last line to one matrix and finalline is the last row to another matrix

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Cells(FinalLine + 3, "B").FormulaArray = _
"= MIN(IF(B739:B" & (FinalLine - 2) & "=5 , A$739:A$" & (EndLine + 2) & ", """"))"
```

Comment: `Cells("B" & FinalLine + 3)` >> `Cells( FinalLine + 3, "B")`

Answer (score 0):

corrected code...

```
 Cells( FinalLine + 3,"B").FormulaArray = "= Min(If(B739:B" & FinalLine - 2 = FinalLine + 10 & " , A$739:A$" & EndLine + 2 & ", """"))"
```